# Clarification of the Ruby Socket Library Gets Method

Tags: ruby, sockets, http, httprequest

I am working on an assignment where I have to develop a web server in Ruby using the `socket` library. I was able to get a simple web server up and running as seen in this thread [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32665884/ruby-web-server-hanging-when-trying-to-parse-http-request/32666197) .

I am currently working on getting and storing the body of an HTTP request into a variable in my web server. The problem I am running into is trying to define a `while` loop that gets the entire body of a HTTP request.

I am attempting to get the body of a HTTP request by using the `gets` method. I could not find any documentation on this method (I saw it being used [here](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/socket/rdoc/TCPSocket.html))
and was wondering if there were more documentation online.

In my first post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32665884/ruby-web-server-hanging-when-trying-to-parse-http-request/32666197), someone suggested that I use the `Content-Length` header to determine the size of the body and how much data to read from the socket. I don't really understand how I would go about implementing this because I am unsure how the `gets` method functions.

Since this is for an assignment, I don't think posting code would be a good idea. I am looking for more information on the `gets` method and any tips to point me towards the right direction.

Comment: I believe that gets is a loop that retrieves everything in the socket without telling it how much data you have in. It retrieves until there's no more.

Comment: From my previous question, someone said that the `gets` method listens to the socket for data. I'm just not sure how to break out of the `while` loop if there is no data to get rather than continue waiting for data.

Comment: The methods are on [`IO`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/IO.html) (a `Socket` is a subclass of `IO`). In particular see [`gets`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/IO.html#method-i-gets) and [`read`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/IO.html#method-i-read).

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't be using `gets`. `gets` tries to read complete lines (ie it reads up to a line separator), but there is no guarantee that an http request body ends with a line separator.

Instead you should be using `read` - this allows you to read an arbitrary amount of data (as you mentioned you can use the content length header to know how much to read)

Answer (score 1):

Your ultimate problem isn't related to gets, or even really anything in your code. But before we get to that, let's answer this question & explore sockets a little bit.

If you follow the chain up, you find that Ruby's [`TCPSocket` class](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/socket/rdoc/TCPSocket.html) inherits from its [`IO` class](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/IO.html). It's `IO` that [provides `gets`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/IO.html#method-i-gets). `gets` will read, line-by-line, until there's nothing more to read. Let's create a simple client that connects to a port, spits out 4 lines of poetry, and then quits:

```
# poetry_sender.rb
require 'socket'

poem = ["'God save thee, ancient Mariner!",
        "From the fiends, that plague thee thus!—",
        "Why look'st thou so?'—With my cross-bow",
        "I shot the ALBATROSS."]

puts "Client establishing connection..."
s = TCPSocket.new 'localhost', 2000

puts "Client sending poetry..."
poem.each { |line| s.puts line } # Print each line out on the socket

s.close # Close our socket
puts "All done."
```

And a simple server, that displays what the client sends us:

```
# poetry_receiver.rb
require 'socket'

server = TCPServer.new 2000 # Server bind to port 2000

loop do
  puts "Server now awaiting some poetry..."
  socket = server.accept    # Wait for a client to connect
  while line = socket.gets
    puts "A client sent us this beautiful line: #{line}"
  end
  puts "They had nothing more to say; let's disconnect them."
  socket.close
end
```

If you run the server (`poetry_receiver.rb`) first, and then the client, you'll see some output like this:

```
Server now awaiting a connection...
A client sent us this beautiful line: 'God save thee, ancient Mariner!
A client sent us this beautiful line: From the fiends, that plague thee thus!—
A client sent us this beautiful line: Why look'st thou so?'—With my cross-bow
A client sent us this beautiful line: I shot the ALBATROSS.
They had nothing more to say; let's disconnect them.
Server now awaiting a connection...
```

The last two lines are the important ones; they indicate that `socket.gets` returned `nil` and we exited the `while` loop.

So, how can we modify our `poetry_sender.rb` so the server doesn't detect the end of the poem? You might think it's got something to do with blank lines, but if you set `poem = []` or `poem = ["", "", ""]` then you'll find that it still gets disconnected OK. But what if we added a delay before closing the socket in `poetry_sender.rb`?

```
sleep 60
s.close # Close our socket
puts "All done."
```

Now you'll see a big delay in the server output. The TCP server doesn't break out of its `while` loop until the TCP client closes its socket.

---

Now we can turn to your broader problem: you're trying to implement a simple HTTP server, but your server is getting hung up in a `while` loop when you try to connect via your web browser. It's because your web browser is keeping that socket open; **but it has to, otherwise it has no way to send you back a response**. So, how do we know when a client has finished sending us a response? The [HTTP 1.1 spec says](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230#section-2.1):

> A client sends an HTTP request to a server in the form of a request message... followed by header fields... **an empty line to indicate the end of the header section**, and finally a message body containing the payload body (if any).

Let's not worry about the message body; how could we write a `while` loop that terminates if it has no more impact, *or* if it receives a blank line? Here's one way, in a simple HTTP server that just sends back "Hello world" no matter what request it receives:

```
require 'socket'

server = TCPServer.new('localhost', 2345)
http_request = [] # We'll store the lines of our incoming request here.

loop do
  socket = server.accept

  while (line = socket.gets) && line.chomp != '' # While the client is connected, and hasn't sent us a blank line yet...
    http_request << line
  end

  # Send response headers
  socket.print "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n" +
               "Content-Type: text/plain\r\n" +
               "Connection: close\r\n" +
               "\r\n"

  # Send response body
  socket.print "Hello world!"
  socket.close
end
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation but you seem to have addressed the problem that I was having previously. I am able to store the request line and headers of a HTTP request, but I am stuck on getting a HTTP requests BODY (if it has one).

Comment: Sure, but the principle is the same: `gets` on a socket returns `nil` when the socket is closed, and the client won't close the socket until you've sent a response. So you need to find another way to determine that you've received all input. One way is to define some helper methods, and include a `break if all_headers_received? && (no_body_required? || all_body_received?)` inside your loop. `all_headers_received?` returns true if the client's sent a blank line, `no_body_required?` returns true for a GET/false for a POST, & `all_body_received?` checks the body against the content-length header.

Answer (score 0):

Quite late to the party, but I'm currently implementing my own rack app server (for fun).

Here you can see how I do it: https://github.com/tak1n/reifier/blob/master/lib/reifier/request.rb

The first line of a HTTP request is always the request line, which is basically something like `GET /test HTTP/1.1`

After the request line until `\r\n` you get the headers.

After that you are able to read the body (if PUT / POST request) with just using the `CONTENT_LENGTH` you parsed from the headers.